# ListPicker woes - how do I save the default value for return visits?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone, listpicker

I'm currently trying to update my app's setting page by using a `ListPicker`.

I've been reading around and have got it linked up to my IsolatedStorage. However, with my current code if I select an option, leave the page then go back, the `SelectedIndex` setting has been saved, but the `SelectedItem` isn't. If I use the same code for `SelectedItem` as I do for the `SelectedIndex`, I get errors.

```
<toolkit:ListPicker x:Name="defaultPicker"
            SelectedIndex="{Binding Source={StaticResource appSettings}, Path=LanguageSetting, Mode=TwoWay}"
            Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="5">
                <toolkit:ListPickerItem Content="Cesky"/>
                <toolkit:ListPickerItem Content="English"/>
                <toolkit:ListPickerItem Content="Deutsch"/>
  </toolkit:ListPicker>
```

How can I make the selected option in the `ListPicker` save so then when a user returns to the setting page after leaving, the previous option they selected is listed as the initial value shown?

Thanks in advance!

Edit: I have made amendments to my code so then my `ListPickerItem` are now databound. But I am still having the same issue.

**XAML**

```
<DataTemplate x:Name="ListPickerItemTemplate">
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
<TextBlock Text="{Binding FromClassTaxCode}" Margin="10 0 0 0"/>
</StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
<DataTemplate x:Name="ListPickerFullModeItemTemplate">
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
<TextBlock Text="{Binding FromClassTaxCode}" Margin="10 0 0 0"/>
</StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>

....

<StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="5">
<toolkit:ListPicker x:Name="listPicker" 
ItemsSource="{Binding FromClassTaxCode}" 
ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ListPickerItemTemplate}" 
SelectedIndex="{Binding Source={StaticResource appSettings}, Path=TaxCodeLetterSetting, Mode=TwoWay}" 
FullModeItemTemplate="{StaticResource ListPickerFullModeItemTemplate}" 
FullModeHeader="Select A Tax Code Letter..." 
</StackPanel>
```

**C#**

```
public SettingsWithoutConfirmation()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    List<TaxCodes> source = new List<TaxCodes>();
    source.Add(new TaxCodes() { FromClassTaxCode = "Madrid" });
    source.Add(new TaxCodes() { FromClassTaxCode = "Las Vegas" });
    source.Add(new TaxCodes() { FromClassTaxCode = "London" });
    source.Add(new TaxCodes() { FromClassTaxCode = "Mexico" });
    source.Add(new TaxCodes() { FromClassTaxCode = "FSDF" });
    source.Add(new TaxCodes() { FromClassTaxCode = "FDSFDS" });
    source.Add(new TaxCodes() { FromClassTaxCode = "LKJSGFD" });
    this.listPicker.ItemsSource = source;
}
```

**TaxCodes.cs***

```
namespace MyNameSpace
{
    public class TaxCodes
    {
        public string FromClassTaxCode
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. You need to define the items BEFORE you set the selected index. So you have to use a databinding for your items and have to place it before the SelectedIndex.

Comment: Can you provide a code sample of what you exactly mean?

Comment: @Lucius86 
<toolkit:ListPicker x:Name="defaultPicker"
            **ItemsSource="{Binding xyz}"**
            SelectedIndex="{Binding Source={StaticResource appSettings}, Path=LanguageSetting, Mode=TwoWay}"
            Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="5">

Comment: Alas this still seems to be a non-starter - I must be doing something rather silly. I have edited my original question to show what I have updated the code to so as to help explain - I have created the databinding, included `ItemsSource`, created a separate class for the databinding, but I still have the same issue. I thank you for your time so far!